# Set up properties dynamically in DTO object from the output of RowCallBackHandler in spring-boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, reflection, jdbctemplate

Below is my DTO object and I  am constructing SQL query based on the user selection.So,it can be having any set of properties from the DTO class.

```
Eg: Sample SQL queries: (Any combination)
select res.NAME from RESPONSE res ;
select res.NAME , res.CITY from RESPONSE res ; 
select res.NAME , res.PRICE from RESPONSE res ;
....
select res.* from RESPONSE res ; 


@Entity
@Table(name="RESPONSE")    
public class Response{
    
    @Cloumn("NAME")
    private String name;
    @Cloumn("CITY")
    private String city;
    @Cloumn("AMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal amount;
    ...
    @Cloumn("PRICE")
    private BigDecimal price;
    }
    
    List<String> userSelectionList=getUserSelectionList();
    String sql=generateSqlBasedOnUserSelection();
    List<Response> responseList=new ArrayList();
    jdbcTemplate.query(sql,new RowCallBackHandler(){
    
    public void processRows(ResultSet resultSet) throws SqlException{
     Response response=new Response();
    //How will set the properties in Response object from ResultSet.

     responseList.add(response);

    }
```

Comment: It's unclear where you suffer performance and unclear what your use-case is (you want to dynamically select a number of attributes (between 1-160) and return a generic response object (like a map or something ?). Are these attributes simple @Column methods / do you have relationships on your entity ? What are the requirements for the response object ?

Comment: Basically from the query output how can I construct a object Dynamially. Modified the input

Comment: HI @ddewaele
I have modified the question for it to be more clear.

Comment: and what's wrong with just returning a response object DTO where some of the fields are null ? how will you (or the client) decide what fields you are interested in ?. Seems like you are mixing 2 concepts here ... an ORM solution with a relatively tight coupling between the domain entities and the table, versus a standard SQL solution where you would just return a Map of key/value pairs